# Find and print the indexes of a substring in string that starts and ends with a specific character in python

Tags: python

Good day everyone!

Lets say I have a string such as:

```
seq = 'ggtctgaatcgggtcaattggcccgctgagggtcaagtaccgggtgacatttgagcatgagtagatcgaggstggccagtatgcaaacggccgattgacgttaaggctaagcctaaaggtccacaggtcagtccagttagcattcgagtctaacggtatcggatctatttcggaaaaggctcatacgcgatcatgcggtccagagcgtac'
```

In this string, I have a certain sequence (substring) that starts and ends with **atgca**:

```
'atgca......atgca' # there can be any letters in between them
```

How can I print the indexes of **atgca**? I want to print the index of atgca in which it appears at the beginning of the substring i've given above, and also the index of atgca in which it appears at the end of the substring.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify the above code to just check for the beginning and end each time you loop.  I also added a not index1 and not index2 because you need to address what happens if find returns None.

```
start = 0
while start < len(seq):
    index1 = seq.find('atgca', start)
    if index1 == -1 or not index1:   
        break
    start = index1
    index2 = seq.find('atgca',start)
        if not index2:
            break
    print index1, index2
    start = index2 + 1
```

Now that you have the two indexes you could even print the portion of the string that lies between if you wanted.

Comment: Hello! First of all, thank you so much for your reply! I tried your code, however index1 and index2 have the same values. :(

Comment: aaahh my bad! I actually forgot to include a second 'atgca' in my string, that's why I ended up getting the same values. it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

The builtin 'find' function does exactly that:

```
start = 0
while start < len(seq):
    index = seq.find('atgca', start)
    if index == -1:
        break
    print index
    start = index + 1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! I've considered using the find() function, however my question is a bit different than your reply. I have a substring inside the 'seq' string I mentioned above, and that substring starts and ends with 'atgca'. For example, the substring can be: 'atgcagctgcgtcatgca'. As you can see, this substring starts and also ends with 'atgca'. I want to find the start AND end index of this specific substring

Comment: Hi lex. Well, your string seems to have just one 'atgca', so it cant start and finish on that.

Comment: Hey Farkash! Yes, you're completely right about that :) I was pretty confident I did, but turns out I typed 'atcga' instead of 'atgca' haha.